# In Back In Black, did the Kingpin really underestimate Spider-man in a pure hand-to-hand fight?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man

In the [Back In Black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_Back_in_Black) story arc (right after the [Civil War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_War_(comics))), I understand that Peter's probably never been this angry before, but wouldn't Fisk (Kingpin) have anticipated an epic beatdown?  The way he carried himself (confidence, putting on his suit) before the fight inside the prison, you'd have thought that one of the most well prepared criminal masterminds would have had a trick up his sleeve rather than take on a rage-driven Peter in a fight. I was almost expecting him to let Peter know that there's another sniper with Mary Jane in the cross-hairs in the middle of the fight.

Nopes, that didn't happen.  Fisk actually wanted a fair fight against a person who far outclasses him in the strength and agility department.

What followed was probably the worst beatdowns Fisk ever experienced (including the ones against [Daredevil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daredevil_%28Marvel_Comics%29)).

[image]

Have previous encounters (where Peter is known to always pull his punches) given Wilson Fisk **such a false impression?** Or is there something more going on here?

Comment: “far outclasses him in the strength and agility department” — is that right? I thought the Kingpin was generally regarded as surprisingly strong.

Comment: For a peak human, yes he's quite strong. There is no evidence of super-strength (natural or enhanced) that comes up. A few sources (http://marvel.wikia.com/Strength_Scale) say he can probably go upto 650 lbs.  Not the 10 tons that Peter's demonstrated in the past.

Comment: Haven't you played the old Spider-Man games? The Kingpin is always really hard to beat.

Comment: This is specific to the comics canon.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the issues with comics is the fluctuating levels of strength characters display. This is true for Kingpin and Spider-Man, as it is true for all other comic book characters.

In the past, there have been previous occasions where the two have battled and Kingpin has fared quite well in hand-to-hand combat with Spider-Man. In some instances, [Kingpin has actually won](http://marvel.wikia.com/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_197).

It's important to remember that Spider-Man is typically not a brutal fighter. He works hard to incapacitate his enemies. This is the Spider-Man Fisk is the most familiar with, and was likely expecting to battle. It's arguable that Fisk is not aware that Spider-Man is typically holding back. *Back In Black*, however, saw Peter Parker in rare form - one fueled by anger. He was a more brutal fighter, and generally doing things that Peter would not normally do - things like breaking hands and arms of low level thugs. The situation was exacerbated by Fisk taunting the already enraged Spider-Man during the battle.

As the fight draws on, Fisk starts noticing that Spider-Man is fighting differently.

[image: Something seems... different.]

Spider-Man explains to him that he's abandoning all his usual rules.

[image: You're confused]

Fisk will be killed by Peter Parker, not Spider-Man.

[image: I'm not going to kill you. I am. Wait. What?]

Fisk now understands the gravity of the situation. Spider-Man/Peter is fighting unlike he's ever fought before.

[image: Oh, crap. What did I do?]

<sup>[click for bigger so you can actually read the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0WdI.jpg)</sup>

[image: Maybe this was a bad idea.]

Spider-Man doesn't kill; he incapacitates. But Peter is ready to make an exception.

[image: What happened to your friendly neighborhood Spider-Man?]

**Fisk underestimated Spider-Man, because Spidey fought in a manner and on a level that he normally never fights on.**

Comment: He was also probably trying to use his rage against him - assuming he'd fight in a less focused manner he could take advantage of, rather than in a single-minded rage that he did.

Comment: True. That strategy worked rather well for Daredevil where he knocked out a rage-induced Spidey in the ''Death of Jean DeWolf'' story arc.

Comment: Does this version of Spidey not use a web-shooter?  His arms are clearly bare, but he seems to be threatening to use his web right then and there...

Comment: @Nerrolken He has organic web shooters at this point in time. He loses them as a part of the deal with Mephisto shortly after this issue.

Comment: Regarding the last image, did Peter actually do that to Kingpin (and thus kill him)? Or just monologue that he *could* do it?

Comment: @TylerH He doesn't do it. He beats Kingpin within inches of his life though, and warns Fisk that he will come back and kill him if and when Aunt May dies.