# Cases when Spider-Man punches (or attacks) without holding back

Tags: marvel, spider-man

We know that Spider-Man at the very least can lift 10+ tonnes, and that he always tries to hold back his punches so that he doesn't kill his enemies.

But is there a case when Spider-Man punches (or attacks) his enemy with all his might without holding back at all?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82454/in-back-in-black-did-the-kingpin-really-underestimate-spider-man-in-a-pure-hand

Comment: Yes, I think Spider vs Kingpin in "Back in Black" is the best answer.

Comment: An answer here shows a possessed spider-man punching the jaw off the lizard http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77498/how-did-doctor-octopus-survive-even-one-punch-from-spider-man-in-spider-man-2/78620#78620

Comment: @Alistair86 Isn't that scorpion? lol. Well good find though :D

Comment: No Way Home at the end

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can think of a few instances that stand out:

Amazing Spider-Man 270 where he beat up Firelord!
[image: http://comicvine.gamespot.com/images/1300-1028039]

Spider-Man vs Wolverine where he mentions punching Wolverine hard enough to wreck cars. (sorry for low res)
[image: https://m0vie.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/spidermanvswolverine.jpg]

Secret Wars 8 where he beats up Titania (who outclasses him in strength many times over) so bad that she builds a mental block about fighting him in the future.
[image: http://herochat.com/index.php?topic=284.0]

Many more exist but these are some of my favorites.
(edit: added images)