# Has Spider-Man ever singlehandedly defeated a foe that was clearly out of his league?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

My understanding is that, in Marvel, there’s different accepted power levels which are matched by villains on the same level.

Without being fully defined, it is accepted that Daredevil or Spider-Man are street level heroes (meaning street level stories) while the X-Men or Thor are more like galactic entities with foes and stories to match.

As far as I know, each hero usually has their own villains that don’t tend to jump levels (i.e. Spidey fighting a villain from Thor), except in crossovers.

Out of this, the only one I can think of is Juggernaut, but I’m not sure even he can be considered a bigger (more difficult) foe than, let’s say, Doc Ock. However, I haven’t read many Spidey comics.

So, is there a foe (i.e. one out of his league) that Spidey has defeated on his own, in one of his own titles, without external aid from a crossover hero?

Comment: Spider-man's powers were enhanced by the alien symbiote, and even further by the Uni-Power. Are you counting either/ both of those?

Comment: No, I mean raw Spider-Man, otherwise his “level” changes

Comment: @Raj - Spider-Man wasn't wearing the symbiote when he defeated Firelord. The black costume he wore in that issue was made for him by the Black Cat out of regular fabric.

Comment: By definition, wouldn't any defeated foe be *in* his league? Because, well, he defeated them.

Comment: @PeterM of course not. In football (soccer) you routinely see teams of lower leagues beat teams from higher leagues. It doesn’t happen often but it does happen

Comment: My impression was that in many continuities, Spider-Man is very much _not_ a “street-level hero” the way Daredevil is. I seem to recall being told in the late ’90s that his strength was second only to the Hulk’s, for example, and that only after the Hulk got a good rage going.

Comment: Yeah, this is a massive oversimplification. Spiderman stories are often street-level stories, that does not make him a street-level fighter

Comment: @Nacht You remind me of early Superman comics in which he was mostly handling small incident.

Comment: Spidey did beat the juggernaught, though he had to lead him into a freshly laid foundation which quickly hardened around him. It took him a while to break free.

Comment: @KRyan - Spider-Man has never been second only to the Hulk in strength, except maybe when he had the power of Captain Universe. There was an old page from the '60s which said that only the Hulk, Thor, and the Thing were stronger than Peter. However, many super-strong characters had yet to debut back then, and it was made clear in Spidey's first fight with the Hulk that the Hulk was _much_ stronger than he was. That said, it is debatable whether Spider-Man is street level or not, or what street level even truly means, and he is quite a lot more powerful than Daredevil.

Comment: Note that at least back in the early 1980s, Spidey's strength was on par with She-Hulk, Power Man and Colossus. [Graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPvRA.jpg).

Comment: I think in my old marvel universe comics spider-man could lift about 10 tons.   Your A-List super-strength heroes could lift like 50-70 tons and only a few like Thor and Hulk had 'class 100 strength' meaning they could lift over 100 tons.  Super-human agility and spidey-sense give him other advantages especially in defense that allow him to tangle with stronger characters like Titania in Secret Wars and defeat them.

Comment: Spider-man _kinda_ defeats Silver Surfer too in Silver Surfer Vol 1 #14, but Silver Surfer wasn't _really_ trying to fight, he was in a weakened state, and he retreated on purpose to save a child. Spider-Man and the army stop their attack when they realize Silver Surfer is a good guy. It is a cheat answer so not posting.

Comment: @Andy Lester - Spider-Man was put into the same class as a bunch of other characters including She-Hulk and Colossus once, but we don't know what the upper and lower bounds for that class were, so it doesn't necessarily indicate that he was genuinely on par with them in strength. And if you look at their wider histories, it's pretty clear he's not. Both of those characters can lift far more weight and hit far harder than he can.

Comment: Spidey's whole thing is wining against those who outclass him. Strength isn't what he's about at all. He's about not being there when you go to hit him. And getting you to drop a building on yourself. Usually by being a wise ass. But he's still a street level hero. Read "When Cometh the Commuter". You'll learn that Spidey's kryptonite is the suburbs and bus drivers who require exact change.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #270](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_270)*, Spider-Man defeated **[Firelord](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Pyreus_Kril_(Earth-616))**, the former Herald of Galactus, who first appeared in *[Thor Vol. 1 #225](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_225)* and was given his freedom by Galactus in *[Thor Vol. 1 #228](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thor_Vol_1_228)*.

The aftermath of the battle was shown in *[Avengers Vol. 1 #258](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers_Vol_1_258)*, with Avengers such as the Black Knight and Hercules commenting on the extent of Firelord's power.

> BLACK KNIGHT: Galactus, eh? I've met another of his Heralds... the Silver Surfer! If Firelord is even half as tough as the Surfer, Spider-Man must have put up the fight of his life!
>
> HERCULES: I have battled both with and against Firelord... his power is awesome indeed!
>
> [image: Avengers Vol. 1 #258, page 11]
>
> <sub>*Avengers Vol. 1 #258* (August, 1985)</sub>

The black costume worn by Spider-Man in this battle wasn't the alien symbiote he picked up during the original *[Secret Wars](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_1)* storyline, but a cloth replica made for him by the Black Cat, which he first started wearing in *[Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #263](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_263)*.

> SPIDER-MAN: The costume the Black Cat sewed for me! I almost can't believe that I'm putting this on! It looks just like the alien symbiote I brought back from the Beyonder's world!
>
> [image: Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #263, page 13]
>
> <sub>*Amazing Spider-Man Vol. 1 #263* (April, 1985)</sub>

In a much later issue, the Silver Surfer assumed Spider-Man was joking when he mentioned that he'd beaten Firelord once, apparently because he found the claim very hard to believe.

> SPIDER-MAN: No idea, but we better figure it out fast. 'Cause there's hundreds coming. Possibly thousands. And they're all turning into your bad guys... which, no offense, isn't a problem for me. Heck, I took down the real Firelord once.
>
> SILVER SURFER: I highly doubt that.
>
> SPIDER-MAN: Honest! Firelord! Former Herald of Galactus! Boom! Pow! Knocked him out!
>
> SILVER SURFER: I am sorry, Spider-Man, but your Earth humor escapes me sometimes.
>
> SPIDER-MAN: I'm not joking! It was in all the papers. I--oh forget it. Don't know why I'm helping you. You're mean.
>
> [image: Silver Surfer Vol. 8 #6, page 13]
>
> <sub>*[Silver Surfer Vol. 8 #6](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Silver_Surfer_Vol_8_6)* (October, 2016)</sub>

Comment: This answer has a panel of him actually fighting Firelord: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138824/cases-when-spider-man-punches-or-attacks-without-holding-back/139194#139194

Answer (score 38):

How about [Firelord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firelord_(comics)), Herald of Galactus, a character with powers described below

> Firelord wields a flaming staff and is capable of energy projection
> via his eyes and staff. Like all heralds, the Power Cosmic provides
> Firelord with superhuman strength, reflexes and durability, flight,
> mastery of the electromagnetic spectrum and total immunity to the
> rigors of space. Firelord is also capable of travelling faster than
> the speed of light.

Spidey defeats him in [Amazing Spider-Man #270](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Amazing_Spider-Man_Vol_1_270). The Avengers show up only after Spider-Man has won the battle.

Comment: As this is a less popular character it may help to add who Firelord is. My best understanding from a quick read that he is a herald of Galactus, and is on the same level as Silver Surfer?

Comment: This is a great answer, because there is comic proof that heralds of Galactus are out of Spidey's league. Because in one comic, Rhino (a Spidey villian) attacks Silver Surfer (another herald) with his unstoppable charge, and is effortlessly stopped when Surfer grabs his horn and says, "I'm out of your league."

Comment: Thank you.    I didn't read a lot of Spidey - but did read that ish.

Answer (score 4):

In 1989, Spider-Man briefly gained the powers of Captain Universe, using them to knock the Gray Hulk into orbit with a single punch in *Amazing Spider-Man* #328.

[image: Spider-Man versus The Hulk]

This happened during a storyline, *Acts of Vengeance*, where Loki had the evil plan to get supervillains to attack each other’s arch-enemies and take them by surprise.  Conveniently, Spider-Man was able to use his temporary cosmic powers to defeat Magneto (albeit by unknowingly convincing the latter that Spider-Man had too many powers to be a Mutant, and was therefore not useful to Magneto’s plans) and Dr. Doom.  The big fight at the end of the story was against a doomsday weapon called the Tri-Sentinel, created by X-Men villain Sebastian Shaw.

Comment: Cosmic Spider-Man was almost certainly stronger and more powerful than the Grey Hulk though, so he wasn't defeating someone above his metaphorical weight class here.

Comment: @LogicDictates A perplexing philosophical problem, True Believers! If Spider-Man gets a cosmic power-up, pushing him into a bigger weight class, is he beating foes above “his weight class” or not? You decide!

Comment: Asker did mention "I mean raw Spider-Man, otherwise his “level” changes" in the comments, although this is still a valid answer to some extent.

Answer (score -1):

In Amazing Spider-Man Vol1, Spidey defeats the Fantastic 4.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are the Fantastic Four above Spider-Man's power level?

Comment: How are you defining "defeats"...? The FF were all still standing at the end.